# Unknown Crash reports

Tags: android, android-fragments, out-of-memory, crash-reports

I have uploaded an app on Play Store. I am seeing the following crash reports:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4616)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4556)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:654)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5030)
```

Another report:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
  at com.unss.packo.apptest.seven_contact.onCreateView(seven_contact.java:43)
```

I have added multidex support to my Build Gradle. My Build.gradle is as below:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unss.pramod.bindumadhava"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // volley
    // Glide
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.2'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can I solve this? How to resolve class not found exception?

With regards

Comment: Search on google `OutOfMemoryError` and `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Is it because, I have  dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } in my manifest?

Comment: nope . For 2nd exceptions , add `multiDexEnabled `

Comment: Is it because, I have  dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } in my manifest?

Comment: Should I add it in defaultConfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your classnotfound :

add this to gradle.build:

```
defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
...

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

and the outofmemory error:
add this to your application tag of menifest file...

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

after this add your application tag is seems like

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

To query the available memory size at runtime, use the methods getMemoryClass() or getLargeMemoryClass().

Thanks...

Comment: My application tag is   <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Have look at my build.gradle. According to that what version compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' should I use?

Comment: I am seeing these crash reports in my play console. So there is no way to test whether everything is fine. Right now building my app. Will update what happened very soon

Comment: When I open seven_contact fragment, the fragment transition slows up a little, as if it is going to crash but survived. How can we fix this?

Comment: sir i think it is occuring because of main thread gets lots of work ... or may be system can also legs to the process.... can not suggest you the actual answer without seeing the process... if you don't mind capture the video of the process and make the gif of it to upload here... then i can be more sure about your error.... Thank You